# How do you throw from outfield without injuries?

Tags: cricket, baseball, training, injuries

Whenever fielding outside the 30 yard circle, a fielder have to make harder and faster throws(and every time I end up with a painful shoulder).

**How to effectively throw the ball from outfield without shoulder pain/injuries?**

Comment: While I don't have a good reference for it, it's also worth noting that cricket  has taken over a lot of the skills baseball outfielders have had for years for how to get the ball to home plate / the wicket quickly.

Answer (score 5):

This site gives a description of throwing technique for a cricketer:

http://www.coachingcricketexcellence.co.uk/cricket-coaching-advice/catching-and-fielding/how-to-throw.shtml

It describes the side-on technique, where you point with your non-throwing arm towards your target and you then can use your weight to provide impetus to the ball.

For a different, front-on technique, have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCvtnyqG4MM